# Protect ignored route from anonymous access in MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Like the title says, I want to protect a directory from anonymous access and that directory is ignored for routing because it contains static content. 
I should also mention I'm just using the out of box individual accounts identity stuff in my MVC app.
The other catch I have is that I will be hosting as an Azure web app.

Ignore route looks like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Cordova/{*pathInfo}");
```

That works just fine.

I thought I could just add a location exclusion in my web.config:

```
   <location path="Cordova" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

With just that, I can still access the content as an unauthenticated user, so that isn't it alone.

Then in the Web.config, system.webServer->modules section I added:

```
<remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
<add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
```

Now it will deny access to the directory (when using the location element above), BUT it will not allow access to any authenticated user.

I saw a few other suggestions that involved tweaking IIS settings or local directory permissions, but since I'm hosting in Azure, that is not an option for me.

**UPDATE**
I implemented forms authentication in the web config, and manually added the FormsAuthentication calls in my Account controller. AND it works!

So I'm guessing the web.config `deny="?"` in the location element is only enforceable with forms auth??
Now I have the forms auth mixed in with the OWIN cookie auth stuff. I thought one used the other (what happened to app.UseFormsAuthentication?) but its not looking that way. I'm making a mess.

How should I be doing this?

**UPDATE2**
And in doing so now my WebAPI security is broken.